# Maximum salary based on column values in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below data in my sql table in which i need to find max salary I am but the problem here is like    if my college name is c1 then i need to consider salary_college1
        column and if college c2 then i need to take salary from salary_college2.

```
    college  name     salary_college1   salary_college2
    c1       n1       5000               6000
    c1       n1       5000               6000
    c1       n1       5000               6000
    c1       n1       5000               6000
    c2       n2       9000               6000
    c2       n2       12000              4000
```

Expected Result:

```
    college  name     salary_college1   salary_college2
    c1       n1       5000               6000
    c2       n2       9000               6000
```

also if any duplicate is there for same combination then i need to take only one record I m using group by condition on college and name.
is there any way to do this?

```
    select * from(
    select college, name, dense_rank() 
    over(order by salary_college1 desc)r from tablename) 
    where r=1
```

but its giving me max salary  based on salary_college1 i want to consider these column based on college column value can someone please guide me how should i do this.

Comment: Worth pointing out: you've got an ambiguity in what your output should be.  You mention that you want to use salary_college1 if college = c1 (otherwise, salary_college2)... but your expected result includes *both* salary columns.  Your listed 'Expected Result' is simply a GROUP BY on college, with MAX(salary_college1) and MAX(salary_college2)

Comment: Your question and your expected result contradict each other. The question says you need the salary from either college1 or college2, but the result shows both columns. Also, the maximum salary of c2 in college1 is 12000, not 9000 - why is this the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

```
select college
       , name
       , salary_college1
       , salary_college2
from (SELECT distinct TN.college
             , TN.name
             , rank() over (partition by college order by (case when college  = 'c1' 
                                                         then salary_college1 
                                                         else salary_college2 
                                                         end) desc
               ) "rn"
             , salary_college1
             , salary_college2
      FROM tablename TN)
where "rn" = 1
order by college;
```

[Here is a demo for ORACLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e5216f0a4db0fb0c00f119162a43a719)

```
select T1.college
       , T1.name
       , T1.salary_college1
       , T1.salary_college2
from (SELECT distinct TN.college
             , TN.name
             , rank() over (partition by college order by (case when college  = 'c1' 
                                                         then salary_college1 
                                                         else salary_college2 
                                                         end) desc
               ) rn
             , salary_college1
             , salary_college2
      FROM tablename TN) T1
where T1.rn = 1
order by T1.college;
```

[here is a demo for MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4507b2e915fd544bdfa11aedfaeb609f)

Comment: Yesterday I couldn't try the solution so didn't reply.I will try these solution today will Upvode and accept the best answer.Thanks a lot for the answer will try and let u know if it works.

Comment: Hi @PriyaBanerjee, I am happy to help and thank you for your answer to my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT name, MAX(IF(college = 'c1', salary_college1, salary_college2)) salary 
FROM `tablename` 
GROUP BY name
```

The query would be easier if the table would not save redundant (or useless?) data. Why do you save the salary for a college that is not relevant?
This would contain all necessary data:

```
college  name     salary
c1       n1       5000               
c1       n1       5000               
c1       n1       5000               
c1       n1       5000               
c2       n2       6000
c2       n2       4000
```

If you need the other salaries, you could save them as new rows. Are those rows years or why are there different salaries for the same name and college?

Comment: It doesn't return expected result from question.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the CASE WHEN structure.

CASE WHEN allows you to basically have an If/Else clause in your query.  For example:

```
select CASE WHEN name is null THEN 'noName' ELSE 'hasName' END as caseField
from someTable
```

In your case?

You want to check what the college is... and then use a different column in your WHEN/ELSE.

Also, it's worth pointing out... your table design looks pretty questionable.  I mean, if a record has a 'college' value of 'c1'... why is there an entry for college 2's salary?  You might be able to eliminate your problem entirely if you Normalize your database into something like:

```
college | name | salary
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `college`, `name`, MAX(`salary_college1`), `salary_college2` FROM `college` WHERE `college` = 'c1' GROUP BY `college`, `name`
UNION
SELECT `college`, `name`, `salary_college1`, MAX(`salary_college2`) FROM `college` WHERE `college` = 'c2' GROUP BY `college`, `name`
```

This might be doing what you want. Althoug it will not the provide the the result you wrote as expected.

This is what I got:

college name    MAX(`salary_college1`)  salary_college2

c1  n1  5000    6000
c2  n2  5000    6000